# f# generate the cross join two list

Tags: collections, f#, seq

Is there a more efficient way to generate the cross join or permutations for the combination of elements in two lists of arbitrary lengths, in f#?

```
listA
|> Seq.collect (fun a -> listB |> Seq.map (fun b -> a,b))
```

Where...

```
listA = [1;2]
listB = ['a';'b']
Result = [(1,'a');(1,'b');(2,'a');(2,'b')]
```

Comment: Using `List.collect` and `List.map` is more efficient than using sequences and then converting back to list. Specially when the lists are not too large.